# Which set is this piece from?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Which set is this piece from? It looks like a space ship or something.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ship looks like a (possibly) slightly altered build of the alien spaceship from [ETX Alien Strike](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7693-1).

[image]

Comment: thx. yes hat fits with my other pieces as well (in orange as posted earlier)